# Apply the same functions to multiple datasets in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and I have 25 samples of RNAseq results. I would like to apply the same functions to calculate correlation of my target gene (say like gene ABC) to all the 25 samples.

I know how to do this individually. Here is my code to do it:

```
df <- read.table("Sample1.txt", header=T, sep="\t")

# gene expression values of interest
gene <-as.numeric(df["ABC",])

# correlate gene with all others genes in the expression set
correlations <- apply(df,1,function(x){cor(gene,x)})
```

But now I have 25 of them. I use lapply to read them all at once.

```
data <- c("Sample1.txt", "Sample2.txt",..."Sample25.txt")
df <- lapply(data, read.table)
names(df) <- data
```

However, I am lost on how to connect it with the rest of my code above to calculate gene correlation. I have read some of the related threads but still could not figure it out. Could anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: It would help to know what your input and output look like here, as the answer really depends on how things are formatted.

Comment: Wrap up your first piece of block in a function that takes a file name and returns `correlations`. Then, do  `lapply(data,YourFunction)`

Comment: @Marat, could you kindly provide an answer? Sorry, I am a bit new to understand the language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do:

```
files <- c("Sample1.txt", "Sample2.txt", ..., "Sample25.txt")

myfunc <- function(file) {
  df <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")

  # gene expression values of interest
  gene <- as.numeric(df["ABC",])

  # correlate gene with all others genes in the expression set
  correlations <- apply(df, 1, function(x) cor(gene, x) )
}

lapply(files, myfunc)
```

That is the style I recommend for you. This is the style I would do:

```
myfunc <- function(file) {
  df   <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
  gene <- as.numeric(df["ABC",]) # gene expression values of interest
  apply(df, 1, FUN=cor, y=gene)  # correlate gene with all others
}

files <- c("Sample1.txt", "Sample2.txt", ..., "Sample25.txt")
lapply(files, myfunc)
```

Probably you want to save the results to an object:

```
L <- lapply(files, myfunc)
```

For the function one can even do (because `cor()` takes matrix arguments)):

```
myfunc <- function(file) {
  df <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
  cor(t(df), y=as.numeric(df["ABC",])) # correlate gene with all others
}
```

Comment: I got an error `Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default`. However, I do not know what it means.

Comment: @jogo's answer is exactly what I would do, just don't forget to save the produced list in a variable (e.g. `L <- lapply(files,myfunc)`). The error message likely comes from apply or lapply, but the syntax in the answer seems to be correct.

Comment: It was the last line. But the modified version works great! Thanks so much!